# Access DB query help needed

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I Have this ACCESS query:

```
SELECT trans, sum(total) as tax 
FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE matType LIKE 'ad-tax' 
      and trans IN (SELECT trans FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans) 
group by trans
```

And this query:

```
SELECT trans, sum(total) as Total 
FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE matType not LIKE 'ad-tax' 
      and trans IN (SELECT trans FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans)
group by trans
```

I have to search for transactions containing the right matType because **I only need the ones that have tax as an item**.

trans------item-----matType------Total

66.............1...........ad-tax.........9.00

66.............2...........p-944..........60.00

67.............1...........ad-tax.........6.00

67.............2...........p-903..........40.00

68.............1...........p-998..........29.00

69.............1...........p-921..........10.00

etc..

I would like to know how to query: Trans | Total | Tax  in one statement. It has to be from between two dates but I can figure that out myself. I am querying from vb.net if that makes a difference.

Comment: You failed to ask a question or describe the problem(s) with what you have

Comment: It is there just wasn't clear enough I guess, I would like to query trans, total, tax from only the transactions that have a tax item, Im not a pro at this stuff, both queries I posted do what I want, but I would like to join it into one statement so the results are side by side : Trans-Total-Tax

Comment: Thanks for the quick response though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT 'tax', trans, sum(total) as tax FROM PURCHASE 
    WHERE matType LIKE 'ad-tax' and trans 
    IN (SELECT trans FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans) 
    group by trans

UNION ALL

SELECT 'total', trans, sum(total) as Total FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE matType not LIKE 'ad-tax' and trans IN (SELECT trans 
FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans)
 group by trans
```

I don´t have your tables here so I can´t try it better

**Addition: This did not work as you like, so try something like that:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT trans, sum(total) as tax FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'ad-tax' and trans IN (SELECT trans FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans) group by trans ) [FIRST] 
JOIN 
( SELECT trans, sum(total) as Tot FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType not LIKE 'ad-tax' and trans IN (SELECT trans FROM PURCHASE WHERE matType LIKE 'P-%' Group by trans) group by trans ) [SECOND]
ON [FIRST].[TRANS] = [SECOND].[TRANS]
```

Comment: Close, instead of being side by side it added to the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: ok, then make a select on (first select) join (second select) ... something like that in my editd answer - still no Access here, but the idea should be clear

Comment: when I tried (first select) join (second select) it failed.. I have read a bunch and have tried numerous ways and couldn't figure it out.. thats why I signed up here.

Comment: Changed your edited one to left join now it works. Thanks so much I have been messing with that on and off for a long time. Read a lot of stuff but I guess still didn't understand the joins.

Comment: you are joining the two results on the "trans" value